# Unique dropna does not appear to work

Tags: python, pandas, nan

I'm trying to get a unique count of id's based on another column that acts as a flag.

However when the code below is used:

```
df['id_flag_0']=np.where(df['flag']==0,df['id'],np.nan)
df['id_flag_1']=np.where(df['flag']==1,df['id'],np.nan)

grp=df.groupby(other_columns+'flag')
result=grp['id','id_flag_0','id_flag_1'].nunique(dropna=True)


grp2=df.groupby(other_columns)
result2=grp2['id','id_flag_0','id_flag_1'].nunique(dropna=True)
```

Result gives:

```
flag | id | id_flag_0 | id_flag_1
0    | 12 |     12    |     1
1    | 10 |      1    |     10
```

Which indicates that the NaN's are being counted

Result2 gives:

```
| id | id_flag_0 | id_flag_1
| 15 |     13    |     11
```

Which also indicates that the NaN's are being counted

What I actually need for result to be:

```
 | id | id_flag_0 | id_flag_1
 | 15 |     12    |     10
```

Should I be passing something else other than np.nan?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you share your dataframe please?

Comment: `nunique` won't count NaNs by default..

Answer (score 0):

I just realized where I screwed up.

I had an additional groupby and sum() that converted the nan to a 0